# How to assign multiple variables from LINQ statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have a C# object variable `emp` that gets populated from different sources. So, at some point I have an `emp.PersonID`, but no first/last name. Now, the simplest way to get data from storage would be

```
emp.PersonLastName = from p in _context.Person
   where  p.PersonID == emp.PersonID 
   select p.LastName;
emp.PersonFirstName = from p in _context.Person
   where  p.PersonID == emp.PersonID 
   select p.FirstName;
        ...
```

etc. I have about 5-10 variables that I need to get that way. Obviously, each statement will cause a database call for a single column, and in general looks stupid. But I can't think of a way to assign multiple member variables in one shot. Something like

```
using (emp) {
   from p in _context.Person
   where  p.PersonID == emp.PersonID
   select new {
      PersonLastName = p.LastName,
      PersonFirstName = p.FirstName
               ...
   }
}
```

(Obviously, this is just pseudo-code, explaining what I am trying to accomplish)

Comment: What's wrong with your pseudo code (other than `using(emp)`)?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. As the previous comment notes, the pseudo-code is very close to a normal LINQ expression which would return an enumeration (or even a queryable) of anonymous elements where the individual fields are assigned as desired. What have you tried? What _specifically_ was not working for you? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you mean.

Comment: Wow - that was harsh! @RobertMcKee Without `using(emp)` it creates a new object, rather than assign member variables to *existing* object. What I tried - is assigning variables one by one - it's exactly MCVE that I had in mind. And the question is if there is a way to assign multiple variables from multiple return columns in a single statement! I don't know how to better ask... obviously, it sounds quite clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without a better understanding of your types, you can do this:

```
var result=_context.Person
  .First(p=>p.PersonID==emp.PersonID);
emp.FirstName=result.FirstName;
emp.LastName=result.LastName;
```

which will cause only a single database call.  If emp is of type person, then you can just replace it like this:

```
emp=_context.Person
  .First(p=>p.PersonID==emp.PersonID);
```

Comment: Yes, the first approach would definitely work. I was just hoping that there is a way to *not* have to list individual variables. The second approach wouldn't work because it will overwrite member variables that already exist (that was the reason for the question in the first place). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can store the results of an all-in-one query in a temporary variable:

```
var matchingPerson = (
    from p in _context.Person
    where  p.PersonID == emp.PersonID 
    select p
).First();

emp.PersonLastName = p.LastName;
emp.PersonFirstName = p.FirstName;
```

If you're looking for a way to make all the assignments in one shot, you cannot; however, you *may* be able to create your employee object in one shot if you don't mind it being a completely new object.

```
// Assume Employee class

var employee = (
    from p in _context.Person
    where  p.PersonID == emp.PersonID 
    select new Employee { 
        emp.PersonID, 
        PersonFirstName = p.FirstName,
        PersonLastName = p.LastName
    }
).First();
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess knowing that I *can't* make all the assignments in one shot is good enough :)

Answer (score -1):

Try code below.  Instead of using anonymous new {...} use new emp() {..}

```
emp =
   from p in _context.Person
   where  p.PersonID == emp.PersonID
   select new emp() {
      PersonLastName = p.LastName,
      PersonFirstName = p.FirstName
               ...
   }
```

Comment: Assuming the variable `emp` actually has the type `emp`, the above can't possibly work, because the LINQ expression returns `IEnumerable<emp>` or `IQueryable<emp>`, which can't be assigned to a variable of type `emp`. Maybe you should wait for the question to make sense before you attempt an answer.

Comment: I know.  Should of included FirstOrDefault(), but I assumed Robert would know that.

Comment: Somebody is *really* generous with downvotes! :( Anyway, the reason that I can't do that (which was the reason for the question in the first place) is that object variable emp already has many other variables assigned. Since three smart people didn't get it from my question, clearly I could explain it better than just say "populated from different sources".